# Undefined subroutine &main using graph package

Tags: perl

I'm using add_edge function in the [graph package](https://metacpan.org/dist/Graph/view/lib/Graph.pod). I want to use a for loop to add edges, but the program returns the message **Undefined subroutine &main::add_edge called at perl.pl line 14**. Printing the vertices within the for loop works. I thought I might need the `Use Graph;` line within the for loop, since that appears to be what some previous answers here suggest, but this doesn't prevent the error.

Here is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Graph;

my $graph = Graph->new;
$graph->add_edges(qw(a b c d));

foreach($graph->vertices()){
  add_edge("$_", "v");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `add_edges` you used before, `add_edge` is a *method* on graph objects, not a top-level function.

```
$graph->add_edge("$_", "v");
```

Comment: Is there a way to use methods within a for loop?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Yes, put the method call inside the for loop. The two features don't interact in any way.

Comment: @eclare, Yes, as shown in the answer. Look carefully; it's not a copy of your code.